# List all opam package versions compatible with a given OCaml compiler

Tags: ocaml, opam

`opam info package` has a field `available-versions`, which lists all versions of a given package that are available **for at least one OCaml version**.

What is much more useful to me, in everyday usage, is the list of package versions that are available **for my current OCaml version**.

For instance, if I am currently on OCaml 4.05.0, and I run `opam info merlin`, I get:

```
 available-versions: 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.1-trunk, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 
 1.7.1, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.2, 2.3, 2.3.1, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2,
 2.5.3, 2.5.4, 2.5.5, 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3
```

But if I try `opam install merlin.1.3`, it fails:

```
[ERROR] merlin.1.3 is not available because your system doesn't comply
with ocaml-version > "4.00.1" & ocaml-version < "4.02.0".
```

Note that `opam list` only outputs a single line (installed version, or `--` if not installed), so it also does not allow knowing which versions are installable.

Is there a way to directly obtain all package versions that are *actually* available (for my current compiler), other than by trying to install each one of them?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to use opam 2.0. You have two options for this purpose:

- `opam list --available merlin` will list things only by looking at the switch, the environment and the merlin package itself. This option should be available in opam 1.3.
- `opam list --installable merlin` will actually run the solver to check if things are ok. This means dealing with the dependencies, in particular. I think this option is new to 2.0.

Finally, the option `--all-versions` allows you to force opam to list all the versions for each packages.